# How can I set up private, per-user sections on Joomla?

Tags: cms, joomla

For this weekend's [GiveCamp](http://givecamp.org/) project, my team has been tasked with adding some functionality to an existing Joomla-powered website for a non-profit.

A certain type of user will login, and have access to a personal area where they can upload files, check for messages, see tasks that have been assigned, etc.

Each user would have their own private homepage They would not be creating additional pages, and their information would only be visible to themselves (or a site-administrator, of course).

None of us have worked with Joomla before, but we'd like to help this non-profit. We're not sure if we're searching using the wrong terms, or if we're just not finding it.

[Community Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/community-builder) seems to have some of what we want -- but offers way more than the client wants.

Is such a solution possible in Joomla without using community builder? Or can we turn off almost everything to get limited functionality? And/or are we better off building some standalone solution that interfaces with the same mySQL database as Joomla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community Builder is really the only one I know that does this for Joomla. I'm sure you can disable certain features that you don't need.